# Unable to connect to wifi [Win-7]

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, dell-inspiron, wifi-driver

As i have gone to the forum, i am not the only one who has faced/facing this problem. But something is strange here, all the solutions provided are not working.

**Prbolem:**
Hardware: Dell Inspiron 3420, TP-Link WR740N Wireless Router
OS: Win 7 Home Basic 64bit

Laptop is unable to connect to TP-link Device 
[See Problem Message Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62G2f.jpg)

but Connects to Huwaie Mobile Wifi device.
There are 10 Laptops with the same specification and problem.
All other Laptops, Mobiles connect to that wireless router without any problem.

**What I Have Tried.**
1) Updated Wireless Router Drivers from Dell Site
2) Release \ Renew Ip by CMD commands
3) Tried Manual IP

none of the above is working.

Kindly guide me, what should  do to resolve that issue.

Comment: What WiFi password security is being used on the router? WPA? Is it what ever the router is using does the network adapter on the laptop support it? Or any firewall that is on those laptops? Try disabling any firewalls/anti virus Windows defender.

Comment: WPA2 personal, is used on TPlink router, the same is used on that huwaie hotspot, but laptop connects correctly to that device

Comment: Have you tried disabling all firewalls and anti-virus virus?